# Binary search with word prefix string out of bounds

Tags: java

I have a program that creates a class dictionary, in which it populates and arrayList of strings with words given from a command line argument(in alphabetical order, all different lengths). Anyway, I need to implement binary search to look for a prefix in the dictionary as part of a backtracking method. I run into problems when the prefix is longer than the word in the dictionary---I tried to adjust binary search for this situation but it is producing incorrect results. I really don't understand binary search enough to fix this issue. If I don't account for the issue of a prefix being longer than a word, it .subString produces string indexoutofbounds. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public int searchPrefix(String prefixKey){
    int minIndex=0;
    int maxIndex= newDictionary.size()-1;
    return searchPrefix( prefixKey, minIndex,maxIndex);
}

public int searchPrefix(String prefixKey, int minIndex, int maxIndex){
    if(minIndex>maxIndex){
        return-1;
    }
    int midIndex=(maxIndex-minIndex)/2+minIndex;
    if (prefixKey.length()>newDictionary.get(midIndex).length()){
        return searchPrefix( prefixKey, midIndex+1,maxIndex);
    }
    else if(newDictionary.get(midIndex).length(<prefixKey.length()&&newDictionary.get(midIndex).compareTo(prefixKey.substring(0,newDictionary.get(midIndex).length()))>0){
        return searchPrefix(prefixKey,minIndex,maxIndex);
    }
    else if(newDictionary.get(midIndex).substring(0,prefixKey.length()).compareTo(prefixKey)>0){
        return searchPrefix(prefixKey,minIndex,maxIndex-1);
    }
    else if(newDictionary.get(midIndex).length()<prefixKey.length()&&newDictionary.get(midIndex).compareTo(prefixKey.substring(0,newDictionary.get(midIndex).length()))<0){
        return searchPrefix(prefixKey,minIndex,maxIndex);
    }
    else if(newDictionary.get(midIndex).substring(0,prefixKey.length()).compareTo(prefixKey)<0){
        return searchPrefix( prefixKey, midIndex+1,maxIndex);
    }
    else 
        return midIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have taken the `binarySearch` method from `Collections` class and modified as per your need.

```
private static int binarySearch(List<String> list, String key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.size() - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;

        String midVal = list.get(mid);

        int cmp = -1;

        if (midVal.length() > key.length())
            cmp = midVal.substring(0, key.length()).compareTo(key);
        else
            cmp = key.substring(0, midVal.length()).compareTo(midVal) * -1;

        if (cmp < 0)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (cmp > 0)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid; // key found
    }
    return -1; // key not found
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't think that this is useful. Given a dictionary "abc", "abcd","abcde"..."abcdefgh", the key "abc" is found at index 2. OP hasn't provided enough input for any reliable coding.

Comment: Yup, it's like checking contains, looking at the dictionary may help to decide.

Comment: @Amy Gold could you share dictionary if you've

Answer (score 0):

The String method compareTo takes care of String values of different length, so that (e.g.) "ABC" precedes "ABCD" so all of these case distinctions in your method aren't really necessary.

The cascaded of statement begins:

```
if (prefixKey.length() > newDictionary.get(midIndex).length()){
    return searchPrefix( prefixKey, midIndex+1,maxIndex);
}
else if(newDictionary.get(midIndex).length() < prefixKey.length() && ...
```

But theses conditions are identical, which means that the second branch is never reached.

You have two statements:

```
return searchPrefix(prefixKey,minIndex,maxIndex);
```

Under no circumstances should a recursive call be made with exactly the same parameters as were passed to the current call: infinite recursion results.

Why can't you use Arrays.binarySearch?

I can't really suggest an improvement because you haven't described the problem. Please provide an example, giving a small dictionary and a set of keys with expected results.